# what is the diffrence between Cursors and baseadapter?

Tags: java, android, cursor, adapter, baseadapter

what is the diffrence between

Cursors and base adapter spically when i wanna use them to show object in list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

huge difference:

cursor is used to go over data , usually from database.for example , go over all of your contatcs/sms messages.

baseAdapter is like a tube to send the data to UI components . for example , i use it a lot for listViews, to set exactly what each item there would have.

Comment: ok if i want to take from DB and show it in UI then i should use both of them right?

Comment: You probably want a `CursorAdapter`.  That will allow you to get a cursor from your DB and display the info on the UI.  I would start out with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, there are plenty of tutorials out there on how to implement that.